# Unmet Dependencies Installing ROS Indigo with Ubuntu MATE on Raspberry PI 2

Tags: raspberrypi, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm trying to install ROS Indigo on my Raspberry PI 2 using Ubuntu MATE 15.04, through the following instructions:
http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM

However once I got up to installing the ROS communication packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-base
```

I ran the line and it came up with an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  Depends: ros-indigo-actionlib but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: ros-indigo-bond-core but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: ros-indigo-class-loader but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: ros-indigo-dynamic-reconfigure but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: ros-indigo-nodelet-core but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: ros-indigo-pluginlib but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: ros-indigo-ros-core but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried installing each package manually but the first one resulted in another set of dependency errors which highlighted both `libboost-system1.54.0` and `libboost-thread1.54.0` package dependencies as well as other ros-indigo dependencies.

If anyone can provide any help it would be much appreciated!! Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224067/unmet-dependencies-installing-ros-indigo-with-ubuntu-mate-on-raspberry-pi-2/) by [adder0210](https://answers.ros.org/users/25568/adder0210/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

15.04 is not a supported target platform for ROS Indigo (see [REP 003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html)) so I'd expect this to be the reason for the issues you see. I'd recommend doing a fresh install of 14.04. I have that running on a Pi2 flawlessly.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adder0210](https://answers.ros.org/users/25568/adder0210/) on 2016-01-15**:
Thanks! I looked more into it and it turns out there is no 14.04 version of Ubuntu MATE so I'll have to go with Ubuntu Core.